# Authserver.exe will not start

Tags: authentication, azerothcore

I proceeded to follow the instructions for **Keeping the source Up-to-Date** and proceeded to compile the code. Now I'm unable to start the server. I get the following error message when starting the ***authserver.exe***. Can anyone help me figure out what I've done? Please advise...

```
AzerothCore rev. 933335d6be8b 2021-06-08 01:35:12 +0000 (master branch) (Win64, RelWithDebInfo, Static) (authserver)
<Ctrl-C> to stop.

   █████╗ ███████╗███████╗██████╗  ██████╗ ████████╗██╗  ██╗
  ██╔══██╗╚══███╔╝██╔════╝██╔══██╗██╔═══██╗╚══██╔══╝██║  ██║
  ███████║  ███╔╝ █████╗  ██████╔╝██║   ██║   ██║   ███████║
  ██╔══██║ ███╔╝  ██╔══╝  ██╔══██╗██║   ██║   ██║   ██╔══██║
  ██║  ██║███████╗███████╗██║  ██║╚██████╔╝   ██║   ██║  ██║
  ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝  ╚═╝ ╚═════╝    ╚═╝   ╚═╝  ╚═╝
                                 ██████╗ ██████╗ ██████╗ ███████╗
                                ██╔════╝██╔═══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝
                                ██║     ██║   ██║██████╔╝█████╗
                                ██║     ██║   ██║██╔══██╗██╔══╝
                                ╚██████╗╚██████╔╝██║  ██║███████╗
                                 ╚═════╝ ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝

     AzerothCore 3.3.5a  -  www.azerothcore.org

> Using configuration file       configs/authserver.conf.
> Using SSL version:             OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021 (library: OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021)
> Using Boost version:           1.72.0
> Using ACE version:             6.5.10

Max allowed open files is 1024
Opening DatabasePool 'acore_auth'. Asynchronous connections: 1, synchronous connections: 1.
MySQL client library: 8.0.24
MySQL server ver: 8.0.24 
Connected to MySQL database at 127.0.0.1
MySQL client library: 8.0.24
MySQL server ver: 8.0.24 
Connected to MySQL database at 127.0.0.1
DatabasePool 'acore_auth' opened successfully. 2 total connections running.
 
[ERROR]: In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 80, sql: "INSERT INTO secret_digest (id, digest) VALUES (?,?)"
[ERROR]: Table 'acore_auth.secret_digest' doesn't exist
[ERROR]: In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 81, sql: "DELETE FROM secret_digest WHERE id = ?"
[ERROR]: Table 'acore_auth.secret_digest' doesn't exist
[ERROR]: In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 83, sql: "UPDATE account SET totp_secret = ? WHERE id = ?"
[ERROR]: Unknown column 'totp_secret' in 'field list'
Closing down DatabasePool 'acore_auth'.
Asynchronous connections on DatabasePool 'acore_auth' terminated. Proceeding with synchronous connections.
All connections on DatabasePool 'acore_auth' closed.
Could not prepare statements of the Login database, see log for details.
Closing down DatabasePool 'acore_auth'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to import the database updates. Currently your auth server is trying to access tables and fields in your `acore_auth` database which don't exist.

https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/database-keeping-the-server-up-to-date

Comment: Thank you for your help... I got the authserver running, but now the worldserver is getting an error...